# session$onFlushed messing up invalidateLater

Tags: r, shiny

I have this shiny app with some textOutput that always start with value 0, then increase over time, after some button is clicked. Since I have to set it to 0 when the app starts, I'm doing so with session$onFlushed. Then to make the value increase over time, I use invalidateLater(). Well, the problem is that before I setup session$onFlushed, the timer were working properly. However, after that was done, it stopped working. Here is some reproductive code:

```
library(shiny)
vars=reactiveValues(start=F,stTime=0)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12,textOutput("cronometro")),
    column(12,actionButton("start","Iniciar")
)
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session$onFlushed(function() {
    output$cronometro=renderText({paste("00:00")})
  })

  observeEvent(input$start,{
    vars$stTime=Sys.time()
    vars$start=T
  })

  output$cronometro=renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    if(vars$start){
      paste(Sys.time()-vars$stTime)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and if I comment out session$onFlushed, everything works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you shouldn't be updating output in the `onFlushed` event. Is there a reference you saw what updated the output in the flush even? It looks like you should only (possibly) update reactive values in that step. I don't understand how you stumbled upon the flush even for this type of task.

But you seem to just want to change a default value of a text output. Why don't you just use

```
output$cronometro=renderText({
  invalidateLater(1000,session)
  if(vars$start){
    Sys.time()-vars$stTime
  } else {
    "00:00"
  }
})
```

Comment: That was the solution that came to my mind, since I only needed to set it to 0 one time, when the app is initiated. Your solution solves my problem, but could you tell me why mine isn't working?